# Multiple knapsack problem with equal profit and different weight

Tags: knapsack-problem

I am researching the load balancing problem in 5G system, but I am not sure if my problem is a NP-complete problem.

The problem is: 
given a set of n items and a set of m knapsacks
capacity of knapsacks are equal.
3. the weight of item j in knapsack i is  w[i][j],that means weight of a item in each knapsack are different.
4. each profit of items are equal.

I am not trying to put all item in least knapsack like bin packing problem.
I saw some similar question answered, but no one is identical to this case.
In this case, the goal is to put as more as possible item with m knapsacks.
Is the problem a NP-complete problem?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriated for this kind of question. StackOverflow is focused towards reviewing code implementation and general programming advice.

Comment: I would post this question to this website. Thank you for your comments.